# Get friends lists from facebook in C# (REST service)

Tags: c#, facebook, rest

I am creating one rest service. in that i want to get the my all the friends from facebook.
i used below code :

```
        string myAccessToken = "App ID";
        FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(myAccessToken);

        var friendListData = client.Get("/me/friends");
        JObject friendListJson = JObject.Parse(friendListData.ToString());

        List<FbUser> fbUsers = new List<FbUser>();
        foreach (var friend in friendListJson["data"].Children())
        {
            FbUser fbUser = new FbUser();
            fbUser.Id = friend["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
            fbUser.Name = friend["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
            fbUsers.Add(fbUser);
        }
```

Here, i am passing accesstoken as my app id. i think, there is the problem with it. SO, what should i pass there ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, i mention in my question that something wrong in passing value of access token.
i found it from here : http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started
After generating the accesstoken , i can get the friends list.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like a dumb response but have you out a breakpoint onto your JOBJECT to see if you are getting any kind of response from FB?

Comment: i am getting error : (OAuthException - #190) Invalid OAuth access token.
At line : 3.

Comment: So, i mention in my question that , there might be any problem , passing TOKEN value. what should be that value ?